# Как можно массово конвертировать изображения на сервере из jpg в webp?

Tags: оптимизация, конвертация, jpeg, webp

Как можно массово конвертировать изображения на сервере из jpg в webp?

На сервере в разных папках расположены картинки в формате jpg, есть ли какой-нибудь эффективный метод конвертировать их в webp?
Если есть варианты (пусть даже платные), дайте знать!
P.S. 18000 + картинок, вручную очень долго буду возиться.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#libwebp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если у вас на сервере стоит php от 5.4 и выше с модулем GD, то можно написать скрипт который конвертирует все картинки в папке и подпапках. https://snipp.ru/php/webp-php - тут написано как в php преобразовать jpg в webp. https://vk-book.ru/poisk-fajla-v-papke-i-vsex-podpapkax-primer-rekursii-2/ - тут как рекурсивно обходить папку с подпапками.
Набросал скрипт. Кладете его в папку с картинками и запускаете. Можно с браузера, но тогда может отвалится по max_execution_time, можно запускать еще раз, продолжится работа. Но 18000 - большая нагрузка на сервер. Тестил на винде, но вроде в линуксе тожа отработает. При работе могут сыпаться предупреждения, это нормально. Просто скрипт пытается из каждого файла получить jpeg картинку, если успех - то конвертим, иначе дальше и предупреждение в логи.

```
<?php 
function jpg2webp($folder){
    $delim="/";
    if(strpos(php_uname(),'Windows')!==false)$delim="\\";
    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) {
            continue;
        }
        $info = pathinfo($file->getPathname());
        $filename=$info['dirname'].$delim.$info['filename'].'.'.'webp';
        if(!file_exists($filename)){
            $img = imageCreateFromJpeg($file);
            if($img!=false){
                echo $filename.'<br>';
                imageWebp($img, $info['dirname'].$delim.$info['filename'].'.'.'webp', 100);
                imagedestroy($img);
            }
        }
    }
}

jpg2webp(dirname(__FILE__));
?>
```

Comment: набросал скрипт

Comment: @ZAKATTACK да, удаление не делал, тестил несколько раз, не удобно было удалять..можно конечно добавить..но не нужно наверно, удалить можно потом массово в операционной системе.

Comment: вы правы, удаление лучше сделать отдельно, ибо у меня на некоторых файлах скрипт не отработал а оригиналы удалил( 
Учусь на ошибках